# How to launch a process that connects to a socket you're listening on?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a process which my code is launching from `subprocess.Popen()` that attempts to connect to a socket my code is also listening on. The problem is if the code starts listening on this socket first, it cannot launch the subprocess. It was blocked by `sock.accept()`, and when `sock.accept()` is times out, it is obviously not listening when `subprocess.Popen()` is ran. If the code launches the subprocess first, it attempts to connect to a socket but then fails before any code is able to listen for it.

Now.. any thoughts on how i can do this? It would seem i would need to start listening in a non-blocking fashion, and then launch the process, but i am a bit confused because even if i use select() to handle the queue, eventually sock.accept() is called and thus blocks the code... i think.

At any rate, some direction would be very handy! I would prefer not to, but if it makes life easier i am not apposed to using Twisted either.

**Edit 1:**
I'll try and get something up in the way of code, i have to look at my old commits to find a working version. Basically though, i don't think my code is the problem. I think i am simply implementing it wrong.

For example, if i launch my socket listener and manually, in a shell, launch this subprocess.Popen() process it connects just fine. This is because the shell is already listening. I *believe* my problem is simply a chicken and the egg issue. In my code, in a single code path, if i launch the process first it fails instantly because there is no socket server listening **yet**. However if i launch the socket server first, it times out because it is blocking and *no subprocess gets launched until it finishes blocking*. My solution, i believe, lies in non-blocking code but i am very unfamiliar with how to achieve this properly. I see many mentions of `select()` but they **look like** they would block at the same point, `sock.accept()`. I say "look like" because i have yet to implement a `select()` version. I may be wrong here, and if i am please let me know.

**Edit 2:**
Here is the socket part of the code.. Note that this is set to non-blocking currently..

```
 90         # Create our socket stream to listen on.
 91         serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 92
 93         #serv.settimeout(5)
 94         serv.setblocking(0)
 95
 96         # Bind the address.
 97         serv.bind(('', self.PORT))
 98         serv.listen(5)
 99
100         try:
101             # Now start listening for a connection!
102             (self._sock, remote_address) = serv.accept()
103         except socket.timeout:
104             logger.debug('Socket connection failed!')
105             raise DBGPServerNotFoundError(
106                 'No connection was established coming from '
107                 '"%(address)s:%(port)i".' % {
108                     'address':self.ADDRESS,
109                     'port':self.PORT,
110                 })
111         else:
112             logger.debug('Socket connection established! The other end of '
113                          'the connection is at "%s:%i".' % remote_address)
114         finally:
115             serv.close()
```

And here is the error..

```
  File "/home/lee/projects/vim-debug/repo/vimbug/dbgp.py", line 100, in connect
    (self._sock, remote_address) = serv.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 197, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The subprocess launching code is in a different module (a unit test, specifically) but here that is for good measure. Note that `con` is a container object, and `con.connect()` is the function for the above code.

```
 56     con.connect()
 57     pydbgp_proc = subprocess.Popen(
 58         ('pydbgp.py', '-d', 'localhost:%i' % OPTIONS['pydbgp_port'],
 59         OPTIONS['debug_file']),
 60         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 61         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,)
```

**Edit 3:** Rewriting code a bit to try out connecting to a socket *before* `sock.accept()` is called. We'll see if it fails :)

**Edit 4:**
Alright. Rewrote the code a bit.. still has the same error. Thoughts? (Also.. this editing junk is getting big.. is there some preferred way in stackoverflow to make these big updates/edits?

Code:

```
 77     def listen(self):
 78         # Create our socket stream to listen on.
 79         serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 80
 81         #serv.settimeout(5)
 82         serv.setblocking(0)
 83
 84         # Bind the address.
 85         serv.bind(('', self.PORT))
 86         serv.listen(5)
 87         self.serv = serv
 88
 89     def accept(self):
 90         (newsock, newaddr) = self.serv.accept()
```

Calling code:

```
 57     con.listen()
 58     pydbgp_proc = subprocess.Popen(
 59         ('pydbgp.py', '-d', 'localhost:%i' % OPTIONS['pydbgp_port'],
 60         OPTIONS['debug_file']),
 61         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 62         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,)
 63     con.accept()
```

Error:

```
       File "/home/lee/projects/vim-debug/repo/vimbug/dbgp.py", line 90, in accept
    (newsock, newaddr) = self.serv.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 197, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 5:** I changed the accept function to the following `select()` implementation, which resulted in `'Not ready..?'` being printed.

```
 89     def accept(self):
 90         rfds, wfds, xfds = select.select([self.serv], [], [], 1)
 91
 92         if self.serv in rfds:
 93             print 'Read ready..?'
 94             (newsock, newaddr) = self.serv.accept()
 95         else:
 96             print 'Not ready..?'
```

Comment: Could you post code for how you spawn the socket and how the subprocess is trying to connect to it?

Comment: What happens when you remove `(self._sock, remote_address) = serv.accept()` and replace with `pass`?

Comment: @Lee, one more question... in Edit 5 above, when you see "Not ready"... have you already tried to connect with the client at that point?  You need to have a client connected before you will be successfully seeing your server in `rfds`

Comment: @Mike, I'm confused on what our platform differences are? I'm running Ubuntu Server x64. (Though, it's a VBox on my windows machine.. but that should be irrelevant)

Comment: @Mike, It's hard to say honestly. I have no control over the DBGp server, all i can do is follow a specification. The server should connect instantly, which is the core problem. It connects so fast, that i had to make sure a socket listener was already set up. So i would like to say yes it has already tried to connect, but i can't say for sure.

Comment: @Lee, I would expect ubuntu and debian to be pretty close... did you have a connected client when you see "Not Ready"... I revised my code below to accept the client... what happens when you run that simple test?

Comment: Ah hah, the server had an error and in some of my tests i was blocking the code by reading io from the subprocess. I'm not sure why it permanently blocked, but it's a bit irrelevant at the moment. Point is, i have a successful connection! I'll be fixing my code and posting a final edit with working code for future googlers. Thank you!

Comment: @Lee, that's great news.  Glad it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting `socket.setblocking(0)` in your listening code?

After you spawn the listening server, you should be able to read the status with `select()` calls... example that runs fine under debian lenny and python 2.5 for me...

```
import socket
import select

SERVER_SOCKADDR = ("", 424242)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)      # <------------------
server.bind(SERVER_SOCKADDR)
server.listen(5)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.setblocking(0)

result = client.connect_ex(SERVER_SOCKADDR)

rfds, wfds, xfds = select.select([server], [client], [], 1)
if server in rfds:
    print "Server socket: accept does not block"
    sockfd, addr = server.accept()    # sockfd.send() and sockfd.recv() to 
                                      # write and read the stream...
    sockfd.setblocking(0)
    print sockfd, addr
else:
    print "Server socket: accept blocks"
if client in wfds:
    print "Client socket: write does not block"
else:
    print "Client socket: write blocks"


server.close()
client.close()
```

And when I run that...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python socket_test.py
Server socket: accept does not block
<socket._socketobject object at 0xb75764c4> ('127.0.0.1', 35810)
Client socket: write does not block
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Comment: Ok, well it seems your client socket doesn't fail immediately so i am going to rewrite mine to listen (and not use `sock.accept()`) and then after launching the subprocess read the results? If that is the correct usage, i misunderstood what `sock.accept()` does. I believed it was the point where data was actually being accepted. Eg, before accept(), all connections fail. I'll report my results. Thanks!

Comment: @Lee, I updated with the results from debian lenny when I run the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Doug Hellman's [Python Module of the Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/) is a good place to find an introduction to a module's basic usage like [subprocess](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/).

Failing that, some code that is causing problems would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can approach this. The simplest is for the subprocess to wait a few seconds before connecting.

It's unclear why you are doing this, can you fill us in on your goal?

Comment: The subprocess is a debug server which adheres to the Xcode specification. So my IDE is actually creating an instance of a debug session. It needs to start listening, so the debug server can connect. I also thought a timer would be the simplest solution, but it seems to be .. lacking. I'd prefer something cleaner and more elegant if possible

Comment: It could retry until it got the connection.

Comment: Yes, but that would assume you have control over the debug server, which you don't. I'm not sure if the Xcode specification says the server should retry X times or not. It's definitely a feature i would have added.